# Is there a standard / built-in way to handle race conditions with CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation?

Tags: swift, multithreading, locking, cloudkit

I'm building my first CloudKit application, and am using CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation on startup to get any new records changed while the current device was offline.

I am also calling CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation when I receive a subscription notification of changes.

It is possible the subscription notification could come in before the startup call finishes.  I am currently using a lock to prevent the 2nd call from starting until the recordZoneFetchCompletionBlock handler is called, signalling that the first one is done.  This works, but it also smells a bit hacky.